# Convert list of values to a list of list indexes for each value

Tags: r

I have a list 'cats.list' with 6 elements. There are 9 unique integers that are members of one or more elements. E.g.

```
cats.list <- list(c(1, 2, 6), c(1, 8, 9), c(3, 4, 5, 7),
                  c(3, 6, 7), c(1, 3, 7, 8, 9), c(4, 5, 9))
```

I want to create a list with one element for each of the 9 integers in 'cats.list'. Each element in the new list should contain the list indexes in 'cat.list' for a given integer.

For example, 1 occurs in the list elements 1, 2, 5 in 'cat.list'. 2 occurs in element 1 only. 3 occurs in element 3, 4, 5.  So the first three element in the new list would be:

```
el.list <- list(c(1, 2, 5), 1, c(3, 4, 5)...)
```

How can I create such a list of indexes for any 'cats.list'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) reshape2** Use `melt` in reshape2 to convert `cats.list` into a data frame whose first column `value` is the element and whose second column `L1` is the corresponding component number in `cats.list` that that element belongs to.  Then `unstack` that with the indicated formula.

```
library(reshape2)

unstack(melt(cats.list), L1 ~ value)
```

giving:

```
$`1`
[1] 1 2 5

$`2`
[1] 1

$`3`
[1] 3 4 5

$`4`
[1] 3 6

$`5`
[1] 3 6

$`6`
[1] 1 4

$`7`
[1] 3 4 5

$`8`
[1] 2 5

$`9`
[1] 2 5 6
```

**2) split** We could also do it this way without any packages.  `rep(seq_along(L), L)` equals `m$L1` from (1) and `unlist(cats.list)` equals `m$value` from (1).

```
L <- lengths(cats.list)
split(rep(seq_along(L), L), unlist(cats.list))
```

**3) stack/unstack** We can also do this using only base R and stack/unstack if we name the `cats.list` components.

```
cats.named <- setNames(cats.list, seq_along(cats.list))
unstack(stack(cats.named), ind ~ values)
```

### Note

We can plot this as a bipartite graph like this:

```
library(igraph)
library(reshape2)

m <- melt(cats.list)
M <- table(m)
g <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(M)
plot(g, layout = layout_as_bipartite)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's a really clever use of `split`!

Answer (score 5):

Use -

```
cats.list <- list(c(1, 2, 6), c(1, 8, 9), c(3, 4, 5, 7), c(3, 6, 7), 
                  c(1, 3, 7, 8, 9), c(4, 5, 9))
output <- c()
for(i in sort(unique(unlist(cats.list)))){
  output <- c(output, list(grep(i,cats.list)))
}
```

**Output**

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 5

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[4]]
[1] 3 6

[[5]]
[1] 3 6

[[6]]
[1] 1 4

[[7]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[8]]
[1] 2 5

[[9]]
[1] 2 5 6
```

**Explanation**

`unlist(cats.list)` flattens the existing list, wrapping it with `unique` and `sort` creates the search list with which you can iterate for the search

The magic lies in `grep(i,cats.list)`, which readily gives what you want for each search.

Putting it together in an `output` list is trivial. Hope that helps!

**EDIT**

Thanks to @ G. Grothendieck, this can be shortened to --

```
output <- lapply(sort(unique(unlist(cats.list))), grep, cats.list)
```

Comment: This could be shortened to: 
`lapply(sort(unique(unlist(cats.list))), grep, cats.list)`

Comment: Note that this would have to be modified if there were multi-digit elements in the components of `cat.list` since, for example, `grep(1, list(1:9, 10:19))` returns 1,2 rather than just 1.

Answer (score 1):

Just to round out the available options here, a version that uses two calls to `sapply/lapply` rather than a `for` loop and `grep`:

```
sapply(sort(unique(unlist(cats.list))), function(x) {
  idx <- sapply(cats.list, function(y) any(y == x))
  return(which(idx))
})

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 5

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[4]]
[1] 3 6

[[5]]
[1] 3 6

[[6]]
[1] 1 4

[[7]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[8]]
[1] 2 5

[[9]]
[1] 2 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse version :

```
tibble(cats.list) %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  unnest %>%
  group_by(cats.list) %>%
  summarize_at("rowid", list) %>%
  pull(rowid)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 3 4 5
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 3 6
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 3 6
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 1 4
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] 3 4 5
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] 2 5
# 
# [[9]]
# [1] 2 5 6
#
```